# translating curl command into java

Tags: java, http, curl

I have to translate a curl command :
**curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'https://terminologies.gfbio.org/api/terminologies/'**
to java.
I want to send this http request to the specified address. The response is then to be stored into a string in java, can you please tell me the translation?

Answer (score 0):

You can archieve it without an additional library with plain JAVA. For JAVA versions v11+ I would prefer the approach @MarcoLucidi suggested.

```
 String content="";
 System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");

 URL url = new URL("https://terminologies.gfbio.org/api/terminologies/");
 HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 urlConnection.setRequestProperty("accept", "application/json");
 
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
 new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

 String inputLine;
 while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
     content+=inputLine;
 in.close();
 
 System.out.println(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using *at least* java 11, you can use the [new built in http client](https://openjdk.java.net/groups/net/httpclient/intro.html). for example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.*;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse.BodyHandlers;

public class HttpExample
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
                HttpRequest req = HttpRequest
                        .newBuilder()
                        .uri(URI.create("https://terminologies.gfbio.org/api/terminologies/"))
                        .header("Accept", "application/json")
                        .build();
                try {
                        HttpResponse<String> resp = client.send(req, BodyHandlers.ofString());
                        String body = resp.body();
                        System.out.println(body);

                } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
}
```

---

```
$ javac HttpExample.java
$ java HttpExample

{
    "request":{
        "query":"http://terminologies.gfbio.org/api/terminologies/",
        "executionTime":"Sun Jun 28 05:00:03 CEST 2020"
    },
    "results":[
        {
            "name":"Biological Collections Ontology",
            "acronym":"BCO",
...
```